# Is it possible to implement test sharding in aws device farm?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, automation, appium, aws-device-farm

I have a test automation suite that uses cucumber-appium-ruby which I run on AWS device farm.
In order to improve performance (and avoid the 150 minutes limit of use per device), I would like to be able to run my tests in parallel (meaning different tests of the suite running on different devices)

I have been looking for a solution to this or if it's even possible, and the only actual solution I have found is to run different sections of my suite per run. This is not ideal since is not a real test sharding, and I would like to know if it's even possible to implement or if someone has done it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the AWS Device Farm Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide) and confirming with Device Farm team (I work at AWS), there is no sharding feature within Device Farm as of June 2023.

You will have to implement a custom orchestrator to poll for available devices of a certain type then shard out tests within a suite across those devices.

Comment: This will run the same tests in multiple devices. OP is asking about sharding (Splitting the test suite and running all the tests in parallel)

Comment: OK, I understand now. Confirmed with AWS Device Farm team and updated answer. Thanks!